# Error via using BETWEEN expression

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need write a query that returns customers who placed orders in 2007 but not in 2008.

Result should look like this:

```
custid          companyname
-------        ----------------
--21           Customer KIDPX
--23           Customer WVFAF
 ...               ...
```

Tables has such structure:

[image: tables]

I don't understand why my code isn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Qone.custid, Qone.companyname
FROM Sales.Customers  as Qone, Sales.Orders as Qtwo
WHERE Qtwo.orderdate between ('20070101') and ('20071230')  ;
```

It return some odd lines. I found solution, which works via using EXISTS - NOT EXISTS structure, but need to understand what is wrong.

Comment: this is ms sql server!

Comment: Is orderdate a date... Why aren't you joining...

Comment: Odd lines are because of cross join, you need to do an inner join as done @Bohemian's Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

After reviewing my answer after reading KekuSemau comment I found you don't need to change your date format

you just need to add a join as you are selecting from two tables

```
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
```

So the Query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT Qone.custid, Qone.companyname
FROM Sales.Customers  as Qone
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders as Qtwo on Qtwo.custid = Qone.custid
WHERE Qtwo.orderdate between '20070101' and '20071231';
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old school join and don't have a join condition, so you were getting a cross join (meaningless results). Use a proper `join` with a condition.

Lastly, you were missing the final day of the year December 31 (your query only included up to December 30).

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Qone.custid, Qone.companyname
FROM Sales.Customers  as Qone
JOIN Sales.Orders as Qtwo on Qtwo.custid = Qone.custid
WHERE Qtwo.orderdate between '20070101' and '20071231';
```

Comment: @KekuSemau thanks - I didn't notice TSQL tag (I don't think it was there before). I've removed the parts of my answer regarding date format.